# text area is not disabling or staying disabled

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, disabled-input

**I have a checkbox**:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="catDescript" class="category_description" name="aisis_options[category_description]" value="category_description">
```

**and a text area**

```
<textarea id="categoryHeader" class="input-xlarge" name="aisis_options[category_header_text]" rows="10" cols="100%"></textarea>
```

and the following Jquery, which is suppose to one disable the text area upon clicking the check box and two keep the text area disabled as long as the check box is clicked.

```
$("#catDescript").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {                
        $("#categoryHeader").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else {
        $("#categoryHeader").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}); 

if ($('input[value=category_description]:checkbox:checked').attr('id') === "catDescript") {
    $('#categoryHeader').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

The problem is, I click the check box, the text area does not become disabled. I click submit the check box is checked but the text area is not disabled.

What am I doing wrong? please post a jsfiddle.

Comment: Your code works in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bvQHt/

Comment: it doesn't work for me and I have the java script wrapped in jquerys document jazz.

Answer (score 4):

For modifying properties of elements,  `prop` method should be used instead of `attr`.

```
$(function() {
    $("#catDescript").change(function() {
        $("#categoryHeader").prop("disabled", this.checked);
    }).change(); // trigger the event on DOM Ready
})
```